# Google Analytics - Filter query - include subfolder / subdirectory

Tags: google-analytics, google-search-console, filtering

I am using CYFE app to view my Google Analytics.

I'd like to filter only traffic coming to my 'blog' subfolder. So I need to filter only traffic that comes to domain.com/blog

CYFE is asking to input the filter in the following query example: `ga:country==United States`

I'm trying to look through GA filters and docs to see if I can find a filter query to include only blog subfolder, but I just can't seem to find anything like it.

What should I be putting in in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your example *domain.com/blog*
and the CYFE query example given `ga:country==United States`

You are looking to match the ga page dimension for the blog subdirectory.
Which would be `ga:page=~\/blog(\/)?.*$`

This should match to
/blog
/blog/
/blog/otherstuffintheblogsubdir

Ref: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference#filters

Comment: Legend, thank you so much, let me try it out, I'll report back.